# PHP cookie writes on incorrect domain

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have a cookie that I use on my app. It looks like this:

```
+-------+-------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
| Name  | Value | Domain                | Path  | Expires  |
+-------+-------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
| foo   | bar   | my.domain.tld         | /     | Session  |
+-------+-------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
```

In a section of my script, based on some condition, I'm trying to change the value of a cookie. I'm using this code:

```
// overwrite cookie
if($condition){
  setcookie("foo", "cat", 0, "/", "my.domain.tld");
}
```

Afterward, my cookie data looks like this:

```
+-------+-------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
| Name  | Value | Domain                | Path  | Expires  |
+-------+-------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
| foo   | bar   | my.domain.tld         | /     | Session  |
| foo   | cat   | .my.domain.tld        | /     | Session  |
+-------+-------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
```

How come a `.` is be prepended to the domain? I want to overwrite the existing cookie.

Comment: makes no sense, it *must* be set to anything.domain.tld otherwise there is a big bug somewhere - the only thing I dare suggest, is that you check again and ensure that the first cookie isn't in fact set to .anything rather than the second..

Comment: Nathan, it looks like it's not a bug so much as it might be a common source for confusion. See the answer below :)

Comment: You might find [`$cookie->setDomain($domain)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L117) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie). It takes care of normalizing the domain name that you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, specifying no domain seems to work:

```
setcookie("foo", "cat", 0, "/");
```

Expected cookie data:

```
+-------+-------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
| Name  | Value | Domain                | Path  | Expires  |
+-------+-------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
| foo   | cat   | my.domain.tld         | /     | Session  |
+-------+-------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
```

Strange, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#93641

The answer is discussed in a post on the php manual.

Cookie data is set by the browsing agent, and so is handled differently depending on the process the browser uses.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

The domain that the cookie is available. To make the cookie available on all subdomains of example.com then you'd set it to '.example.com'. The . is not required but makes it compatible with more browsers. Setting it to www.example.com  will make the cookie only available in the www  subdomain. Refer to tail matching in the » spec for details.

And the tail matching spec is here:

http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html

Comment: I should've been more specific. By `anything` I meant the subdomain could be anything. I didn't want to narrow answers down to a `www` specific subdomain. To be more precise, I don't want the cookie to match *all* subdomains for the domain. I updated my question.